# Retrieving a count that matches specified criteria in a $group aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I am looking to group documents in my collection on a specific field, and for the output results of each group, I am looking to include the following:

1. A count of all documents in the group that match a specific query (i.e. a count of documents that satisfy some expression { "$Property": "Value" })
2. The total number of documents in the group
3. (Bonus, as I suspect that this is not easily accomplished) Properties of a document that correspond to a $min/$max accumulator

I am very new to the syntax used to query in mongo and don't quite understand how it all works, but after some research, I've managed to get it down to the following query (please note, I am currently using version 3.0.12 for my mongo db, but I believe we will upgrade in a couple of months time):

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    GroupID: "$GroupID", 
                    Status: "$Status"
                }, 
                total: { $sum: 1 }, 
                GroupName: { $first: "$GroupName" }, 
                EarliestCreatedDate: { $min: "$DateCreated" }, 
                LastModifiedDate: { $max: "$LastModifiedDate" }
            }
        }, 
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id.GroupID", 
                Statuses: {
                    $push: {
                        Status: "$_id.Status", 
                        Count: "$total"
                    }
                }, 
                TotalCount: { $sum: "$total" }, 
                GroupName: { $first: "$GroupName" }, 
                EarliestCreatedDate: { $min: "$EarliestCreatedDate" }, 
                LastModifiedDate: { $max: "$LastModifiedDate" }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Essentially what I am looking to retrieve is the Count for specific Status values, and project them into one final result document that looks like the following:

```
{
    GroupName, 
    EarliestCreatedDate, 
    EarliestCreatedBy, 
    LastModifiedDate, 
    LastModifiedBy, 
    TotalCount,
    PendingCount, 
    ClosedCount
}
```

Where PendingCount and ClosedCount are the total number of documents in each group that have a status Pending/Closed. I suspect I need to use $project with some other expression to extract this value, but I don't really understand the aggregation pipeline well enough to figure this out.

Also the EarliestCreatedBy and LastModifiedBy are the users who created/modified the document(s) corresponding to the EarliestCreatedDate and LastModifiedDate respectively. As I mentioned, I think retrieving these values will add another layer of complexity, so if there is no practical solution, I am willing to forgo this requirement.

Any suggestions/tips would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation stages.

`$group`

Calculate all the necessary counts `TotalCount`, `PendingCount` and `ClosedCount` for each `GroupID`

Calculate `$min` and `$max` for `EarliestCreatedDate` and `LastModifiedDate` respectively and `push` all the fields to `CreatedByLastModifiedBy` to be compared later for fetching `EarliestCreatedBy` and `LastModifiedBy` for each `GroupID`

`$project`

Project all the fields for response

`$filter` the `EarliestCreatedDate` value  against the data in the `CreatedByLastModifiedBy` and `$map` the matching `CreatedBy` to the `EarliestCreatedBy` and `$arrayElemAt` to convert the array to object.

Similar steps for calculating `LastModifiedBy`

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate(
    [{
        $group: {
            _id: "$GroupID",
            TotalCount: {
                $sum: 1
            },
            PendingCount: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: {
                            $eq: ["Status", "Pending"]
                        },
                        then: 1,
                        else: 0
                    }
                }
            },
            ClosedCount: {
                $sum: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: {
                            $eq: ["Status", "Closed "]
                        },
                        then: 1,
                        else: 0
                    }
                }
            },
            GroupName: {
                $first: "$GroupName"
            },
            EarliestCreatedDate: {
                $min: "$DateCreated"
            },
            LastModifiedDate: {
                $max: "$LastModifiedDate"
            },
            CreatedByLastModifiedBy: {
                $push: {
                    CreatedBy: "$CreatedBy",
                    LastModifiedBy: "$LastModifiedBy",
                    DateCreated: "$DateCreated",
                    LastModifiedDate: "$LastModifiedDate"
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            GroupName: 1,
            EarliestCreatedDate: 1,
            EarliestCreatedBy: {
                $arrayElemAt: [{
                    $map: {
                        input: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$CreatedByLastModifiedBy",
                                as: "CrBy",
                                cond: {
                                    "$eq": ["$EarliestCreatedDate", "$$CrBy.DateCreated"]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        as: "EaCrBy",
                        in: {
                            "$$EaCrBy.CreatedBy"
                        }
                    }
                }, 0]
            },
            LastModifiedDate: 1,
            LastModifiedBy: {
                $arrayElemAt: [{
                    $map: {
                        input: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$CreatedByLastModifiedBy",
                                as: "MoBy",
                                cond: {
                                    "$eq": ["$LastModifiedDate", "$$MoBy.LastModifiedDate"]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        as: "LaMoBy",
                        in: {
                            "$$LaMoBy.LastModifiedBy"
                        }
                    }
                }, 0]
            },
            TotalCount: 1,
            PendingCount: 1,
            ClosedCount: 1
        }
    }]
)
```

Update for Version < 3.2

`$filter` is also not available in your version. Below is the equivalent.

The comparison logic is the same and creates an array with for every non matching entry the value of `false` or `LastModifiedBy` otherwise.

Next step is to use `$setDifference` to compare the previous array values with array `[false]` which returns the elements that only exist in the first set.

```
LastModifiedBy: {
    $setDifference: [{
            $map: {
                input: "$CreatedByLastModifiedBy",
                as: "MoBy",
                in: {
                    $cond: [{
                            $eq: ["$LastModifiedDate", "$$MoBy.LastModifiedDate"]
                        },
                        "$$MoBy.LastModifiedBy",
                        false
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        [false]
    ]
}
```

Add `$unwind` stage after `$project` stage to change to object

```
{$unwind:"$LastModifiedBy"}
```

Similar steps for calculating `EarliestCreatedBy`

Comment: `$$` syntax to access the intermediate variable during iteration. Ex `CrBy` & `EaCrBy` . Little more here https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/aggregation-variables/

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I read through it, and I think it should suit my needs, but it seems like it's not working for me. I believe the $arrayElemAt expression is not supported in my mongo db's version 3.0.12 (sorry I should have specified that in my question). Do you know of a way to perform a similar operation in this version? If not I can make do for now; I believe we are looking to upgrade our db to the latest version in a couple of months.

Comment: No worries. You are welcome. Included the update for your version.